# Rsyslog imfile equivalent for Android non-root?

Tags: logs, android, syslog

I am on Android 13 and use an app (not my app) that generates csv log files with tens of thousands of lines.
I am trying to get these log entries to my central log server in the easiest and most performant way possible.

My current solution is a bash script in termux that reads the csv file line by line and pipes that line to netcat which sends the entry with specified source port to the log server.

The problem is that netcat is extremely slow, running at about 10 packets per second (as in RFC 5426, one log message per packet). This would mean 10,000 lines could take over 15 minutes just to send one log file over the network.
I've tested the limits of rsyslog over similar network conditions, and it can do between 5,000 and 15,000 packets per second (with a log file in the hundreds of thousands of lines).

Obviously, this is not the most optimal solution. My other idea was to use a network share and drop the entire csv log file in a folder that the log server can access. Then have the log server have a script to process this file in with rsyslog. This is more performant, but a more complex setup and relies on additional devices, scripts, and creating a rather unnecessary communication channel in my network.

What would be the best (easy and performant) solution for non-rooted android to send a log file to a remote syslog server?